# The F12 of the python world

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, definition

In Visual Studio the F12 key will define whatever method or library is highlighted.

How do I see the definitions of python functions and libraries? (sorry if this newbie question)

I am using IDLE on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: IDLE does not do code analysis beyond syntax highlighting.

Comment: Is it possible to code analysis from the commandline?  Or do i need to go to a web-base repository?